# Silverlight: How do I tell panels to remeasure and arrange their contents?

Tags: silverlight

I've got a cutom panel class and a property called MaxColumns. When this property is changed I need to force my control to remasure and arrange its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have overridden the ArrangeOverride and MesaureOverride methods, just have the control call InvalidateMeasure() when the (Dependency)property MaxColumns changes.

Look to Silverlight Toolkit's implementation of WrapPanel as an example.

Comment: I have a similar problem -- when removing an item from WrapPanel.Children, how do I get the WrapPanel to remeasure and update its ActualHeight?